# PHP Code for printing the difference between the number of days from Date of Birth to the current date

Tags: php

PHP Code for printing the difference between the number of days from 
Date of Birth to the current date such that it should accept the Date of birth
in Date field and Current date should be Printed from the system current date.

EXAMPLE
Dateofbirth: 25-02-2014. 
Current date: 17-11-2014. 
RESULT:Number of days:266.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself? There's more than enough information in PHP's docs to come up with a solution

Comment: @Kiran , A direct answer already there in the PHP official site... Why don't you search before posting here. Check this link --> http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

See the `DateTime`:

```
$born_date = new DateTime('25-02-2014');
$diff = $born_date->diff(new DateTime());
echo $diff->days.' days';

// returns '272 days'
```

Comment: I'd recommend you don't leave answers to bad questions, it will only encourage more bad questions.

Comment: @GordonM: sure, you don't need to answer to bad questions, you can downvote bad question but there is no reason to downvote correct answer.

Comment: I didn't.  Someone else did.